# JQuery Ajax Form and Dynamically created form elements not submitting

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm writing a form that has some text input elements loaded dynamically when a select list is changed.

The problem is that when I submit the form those elements are not sent in the data that is posted to the server.

What do I need to do to get those dynamically created elements "into" the form to be submitted?

The code is something like this:

```
$("#my_select_id").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "some-url/" + $("#played_number_game_id").children("option:selected").val(),
        async: false, 
        dataType: "html",
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, status, errorThrown) {
            alert("oh no!");
            alert(status);
        },
        success: function (data, status) {
            $("#parent-element").html("");
            $("#parent-element").append(data);
        },
        complete: function() {
        }
    });

    $("#my_form_submit").click(function() {
        $("#my-form").ajaxSubmit({ clearForm: true }); 
        return false;
    });
});
```

The html returned by the ajax call is:

```
<input id="my-form_e_1" class="number-input" type="text"/>
<input id="my-form_e_2" class="number-input" type="text"/>
```

And if I use firebug to look at the page after calling the ajax method the dynamically loaded html is right in the hierarchy where it should be...i.e. it's in the form.

But when I click the submit button only the elements of the form that existed before the ajax call get posted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that the dynamically added input elements do not have `name` attributes. Input elements require `name` attributes if you want their values to be included in the submitted data.

Comment: @Mike: How else are the inputs supposed to be submitted? That's the *name* that shows up in the POST vars...that's how you access them.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, just append the form element to the body tag and set its style to 'display:none'