# jQuery: Problem with submission of dynamic form elements

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic, submit, element

I'm trying to submit a form which contains dynamic elements that were added to the DOM by jQ after the page has completed loading.

When I run a serialize() on the form, it's grabbing the data for all fields that are hardcoded into the page - but not the dynamic fields.

Here are some code snippets of the same..

**HTML**

```
<form id="someform" name="someform" method="post" action"">
    <input type="text" name="afield" />
 <ul id="somelist">
 </ul>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<img id="add" src="add-button.png" />

<div class="new_unit" style="display:none">
 <input type="text" name="somefield" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Adds a new field to the form
$( '#add' ).click( function() {
 $( '#somelist' ).append( '<li>' + $( '.new_unit' ).html() + '</li>' );
});

// Validate before submission
$( '#someform' ).validate({
 .......,
 .....,
 submitHandler: submit_form
});

function submit_form() {
 _data = $( '#someform' ).serialize();
 alert( _data );
}
</script>
```

Upon hitting the submit button, data in the static field, **afield** is showing up... but any of the **somefields** added by jQuery aren't.

I found a couple of [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898508/jquery-ajax-form-and-dynamically-created-form-elements-not-submitting) here. I'm complying to the suggested solution yet no effect.

I'm using the latest jQuery (1.4.1) - and have considered playing with the live() event binder. I have a feeling that may help solve this issue, but cannot figure out how to use it in conjunction with the validate() plugin.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks,
m^e

Comment: Hmm, your code literally pasted into a test file with links to google's hosted jquery, and ms's hosted jquery.validate works for me. At least in firefox 3.6. I can give you a copy of the complete test file if you want

Comment: Grrrr... the darned thing wouldn't! For me, at least.. till I included those []. Most likely the issue of multiple instances of similarly named fields, I guess. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your dynamically added fields are all named the same. You either have to give them different names or, depending on what you use on the server, you could give them a name like `somefield[]` to aggregate them (PHP and I believe Python deal with this).

To give them a different name, it might be slightly easier to do this:

```
<input type="text" id="copy" />
```

and:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
  $("#copy").clone().removeAttr("id").attr("name", "field[]")
    .appendTo("#somelist").wrap("<li>")
});
```

Comment: Coooool!! Thanks a tonne. The php [] aggregation did the trick. And the clone() feature is a terrific timesaver. Wonder why I never used it so long!