# Input fields added dynamically through jquery not being submitted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have made a table where if a user clicks on a td it converts into an input field with name and value.

The fields are created successfully but are not submitted along with the form.

In My HTML/PHP :

```
            <tr>
            <form action='form_handlers/assign_query.php' method='POST'>
                    <td >{$row['id']}</td>
                    <td class='editable-td' data-name='name'>{$row['name']}</td>
                    <td class='editable-td' data-name='phone_no'>{$row['phone_no']}</td>
                    <td class='editable-td' data-name='email'>{$row['email']}</td>
                    <td class='editable-td' data-name='type'>{$row['type']}</td>
                    <td class='short-cell editable-td textarea'  data-name='query'>
                        <div class='scrollable'>{$row['query']}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class='editable-td' data-name='agents'>{$row['agents']}</td>
                    <td class='editable-td'><button type='submit' class='cstm-btn' name='update_query'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button></td>
            </form>
            </tr>
```

In my Js :

```
$('.editable-td').dblclick(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('enabled')) {
        console.log('already enabled');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('enabled');
        if($(this).hasClass('textarea')) {
            var text_content = $(this).find('.scrollable').html();
            var name = $(this).data('name');
            console.log(name);
            $(this).html("<textarea name='"+name+"'>"+ text_content +"</textarea>");
        }
        else {
            var text_content = $(this).html();
            var name = $(this).data('name');
            console.log(name);
            $(this).html("<input type='text' name='"+name+"' value='"+ text_content +"' ></input>");
        }
    }
});
```

In form_hanlders/assign_query.php :

```
<?php 
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Input fields dynamically added by jQuery don't show up in $_POST array. But if I manually type in the exact same line that jQuery generates and paste it in the td, it gets submitted. Any help?

P.S : I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971014/dynamically-added-input-fields-not-submitting) , and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971014/dynamically-added-input-fields-not-submitting) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898508/jquery-ajax-form-and-dynamically-created-form-elements-not-submitting) and they don't help.

Comment: Why do you pass html into created `textarea` tag by `text_content` variable but not just text?

Comment: readable code i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a `form` element as a child of a `tr`. If you check the HTML in the dev tools DOM inspector you'll see that the `form` element has either been moved outside of the table (so it no longer contains the `input` or `textarea` elements) or it has been removed completely.

To fix the problem the form needs to wrap the entire `table`, like this:

```
<form action="form_handlers/assign_query.php" method="POST">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>{$row['id']}</td>
        <td class="editable-td" data-name="name">{$row['name']}</td>
        <!-- additional cells... -->
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I am sure that would solve the problem but I cant wrap the table in the form since I have multiple rows in the table. Like a record table and every row has to have a separate form that can be edited. any workaround? Thanks for your help

Comment: Not really. You either need to use AJAX and only send updated rows, send the entire table and determine the changed values on the server, or alternatively don't use a `table`